# Misconception in sample space, event space of a picking a ball question

Tags: probability

I have been revising a bit on probability and stuck on the most basic definition of sample space, event space and outcomes.

Consider 10 balls, 6 red and 4 black, in which 3 of the 6 red balls are round and 1 of the black balls is round. What is the probability of picking a round ball given it is red. Well I do not have any problem plugging in formula to get $$P(A|B) = \dfrac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{3}{10} \div \frac{3}{5} = \frac{1}{2}$$ where $A$ is the event of a round ball and $B$ is the event of a red ball.

However, I wish to understand what is the sample space and event space of this problem... I am extremely confused whether my sample space should be $$S = \{red, black\}$$ or $$S = \{red,black, round, not ~ round\}$$

In either case, I am still unsure what my event A and B is when represented as a set notation. By definition, A and B MUST BE  a subset of the sample space. But in either case, event A or B does not seem to fall into a subset of the sample space above.

I am sure I am missing out some things here, please help correct my misconception.

PS: to be fair, I do not even know what my experiment (probability space is). They say an experiment should be pre-defined and I am not even sure what the experiment in this setting is. I also failed to mimic the idea from simple examples like rolling 2 dices to this problem.

Comment: Your sample space could be the set of possible outcomes: *pairs* (red, round), (red, not round), (black, round) and (black, not round). Similarly in the case of rolling 2 dice.

Comment: @Berci thanks for the reply. So what would the event A and B be since A and B must be a subset of the sample space you defined.

Comment: Because  the problem says "given that it is red" your sample space is the set of all red balls.  Three of the six red balls are round so the probability a ball is round, given that it is red, is 3/6= 1/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that new students of probability seem to not have explained properly is that *we have our own choice* as to which sample space to use to describe a problem.  It is entirely up to us so long as the events that we are interested in discussing the probabilities of are subsets of the sample space that we chose and each result of an experiment is described uniquely by exactly one of the outcomes in the sample space.  In your attempt of a sample space of $\{red,black,round,notround\}$ by drawing a red round ball, two of your outcomes describe this, there wasn't a unique outcome that matched the result of your experiment.

There are some suggestions however when choosing a sample space.  First is simplicity.  If we were talking about the probability of winning a game of monopoly against friends, we could just talk about the final overall outcomes of who won with no other additional information.  Or, we could make it horrendously complicated, talking instead about every possible move throughout the game or even talking about what you ate for breakfast that morning, etc...  where most of the information winds up not being relevant or necessary to answer any of the questions involved.

Next, we also tend to prefer sample spaces who are equiprobable, each outcome in the sample space being equally likely to occur.  We like these choices of sample spaces since in such a scenario we can use counting techniques to calculate probabilities by taking the ratio of the size of the event compared to the size of the sample space, something which cannot be done in general.

---

Finally, note that in your specific problem, we may *temporarily assume the balls are uniquely numbered*!  Yes, the balls might not have been numbered in reality, but by temporarily assuming they were numbered you should be able to convince yourself that the probabilities of selecting a ball of a certain type would stay the same as if they weren't and this now allows us to describe the problem with an equiprobable sample space.

Here, we can let the balls be numbered $1,2,3,\dots,10$.  The three red round balls being labeled $1,2,3$, the not round red balls being $4,5,6$, the black round ball being $7$, and the black not round balls being $8,9,10$.

Our sample space then is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.  Our event $A$ is $\{1,2,3,7\}$, our event $B$ is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, etc...

Comment: I assume you meant to write something along the lines of we also tend to prefer sample spaces in which the outcomes are equiprobable.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig perhaps I had learned poor grammar in this context, but I have certainly heard and used "An equiprobable sample space" to be in reference to a sample space in which each outcome inside of it as being equally likely to occur.  The intention of the meaning should be understandable in any case.

Comment: As usual, you wrote a good answer.  It was your use of the word who for the sample space that elicited the grammarian in me.